# generate multiple random passwords at once in batch

Tags: batch-file

So i wanted to generate passwords in batch, i found this code on the internet:

It works very good, but only problem is i don't know how to loop it
I tried looping it by putting goto start at the end but then it just breaks and shortens the password until it's like 2 characters long and i dont want that to happen, i also tried copy pasting the code a bunch of times ,same result, then i tried copying the last 6 lines but then it would just make the code longer, i want it to be the same length, does anyone know how

````
:start
color 0a
set lengthnumberuser=32
cls
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set _RNDLength=%lengthnumberuser%
Set _Alphanumeric=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789
Set _Str=%_Alphanumeric%987654321
:_LenLoop
IF NOT "%_Str:~18%"=="" SET _Str=%_Str:~9%& SET /A _Len+=9& GOTO :_LenLoop
SET _tmp=%_Str:~9,1%
SET /A _Len=_Len+_tmp
Set _count=0
SET _RndAlphaNum=
:_loop
Set /a _count+=1
SET _RND=%Random%
Set /A _RND=_RND%%%_Len%
SET _RndAlphaNum=!_RndAlphaNum!!_Alphanumeric:~%_RND%,1!
If !_count! lss %_RNDLength% goto _loop
Echo ID: !_RndAlphaNum!```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to keep on looping, until <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> are pressed?

```sh
@Echo Off & SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "i=-1" & For %%_ In (A B C D F G H I J K L M N P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9) Do (Set /A i += 1 & Set "$.!i!=%%_")
:Loop
Set "strAN=" & For /L %%_ In (1 1 32) Do (Set /A "#=!RANDOM! %% i"
    For %%_ In (!#!) Do Set "strAN=!strAN!!$.%%_!")
Echo(%strAN%
GoTo :Loop
```

*Where `32)` determines the number of alphanumeric characters in your resulting string.*

---

Or do you want a specific number of alphanumeric strings to be generated?

```sh
@Echo Off & SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "i=-1" & For %%_ In (A B C D F G H I J K L M N P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9) Do (Set /A i += 1 & Set "$.!i!=%%_")
For /L %%_ In (1 1 10) Do Call :Loop
Pause
GoTo :EOF
:Loop
Set "strAN=" & For /L %%_ In (1 1 32) Do (Set /A "#=!RANDOM! %% i"
    For %%_ In (!#!) Do Set "strAN=!strAN!!$.%%_!")
Echo(%strAN%
```

*Where `10)` determines the number of alphanumeric strings returned.*